# Como evitar esto al usar nbsp; en React-native con html?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un bloc de notas en react-native y quiero que el usuario pueda escribir en colores, el problema es cuando tengo strings pegados, al hacer espacio, borrar y espacio desde el primer string, los strings pegados a el toman el color, debido al `&nbsp` insertado, entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de evitarlo:

aqui el codigo:

```
 <RichEditor
   ref = {this.richText}
   initialContentHTML = {"<span style = 'color: red'>hola</span><span style = 'color: blue;'>hola</span><span style = 'color: violet;'>hola</span>"}
   style = {{flex:1}}
   placeholder = "Content"
   useContainer = {false} 
   onChange = {(text) => this.chao(text)}
 >
```

asi es como se veria el emulador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema llega cuando hago space desde el primer hola (rojo) luego borro el space, y si vuelvo a hacer  de nuevo el space, los dos holas pegados a el toman su estilo, volviendose rojos tambien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui les muestro la consola que imprime la estructura paso por paso, y veran que al final las etiquetas `<span>` se vuelven `<font>` repitiendose 3 veces, por que pasa esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]