# Como evitar concatenar varias etiquetas en una con &nbsp;? mediante REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

Estoy haciendo un bloc de notas en react-native y quiero que el usuario pueda escribir en colores, el problema es cuando tengo strings pegados, al hacer espacio, borrar y espacio desde el primer string, los strings pegados a el toman el color, debido al &nbsp insertado, entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de evitarlo:

aqui el codigo:

```
 <RichEditor
   ref = {this.richText}
   initialContentHTML = {"<span style = 'color: red'>hola</span><span style = 'color: blue;'>hola</span><span style = 'color: violet;'>hola</span>"}
   style = {{flex:1}}
   placeholder = "Content"
   useContainer = {false} 
   onChange = {(text) => this.chao(text)}
 >
```

asi es como se veria en el emulador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema llega cuando hago space desde el primer hola (rojo) luego borro el space, y si vuelvo a hacer de nuevo el space, los dos holas pegados a el toman su estilo, volviendose rojos tambien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui les muestro la consola que imprime la estructura paso por paso, y veran que al final las etiquetas `<span>` se vuelven  repitiendose 3 veces, por que pasa esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y que tal un boton que te permita cambiar el color del texto que hayas seleccionado?, asi te ahorras dolores de cabeza, pues puede parecer sencillo, pero la realidad es muy distinta pues tendrias que meterte a cosas de programación un poco avanzadas, lo ideal seria poder usar `AWK` que es un lenguaje que te permite procesar y extraer información dependiendo de condicionales, yo lo considero un poco complejo debido a que su sintaxis muchas vecez es dificil de leer si no conoces el lenguaje.

Comment: Por este motivo considero que es mucho mas facil que simplemente implementes un boton que te permita resaltar en algun color el texto seleccionado, ya que si lo que quieres hacer es en tiempo real me temo que tendras que crear un algoritmo que te permita escanear linea por linea y de manera inteligente las palabras, su color y su contexto, asi el programa sabra diferenciar cuales palabras hacian parte de unas y cuales no. yo intente algo parecido hace tiempos pero nunca termine el proyecto por cuestiones de tiempo.

Comment: Por cierto, no te recomiendo usar el `&nbsp`, eso no es bueno para la legibilidad del codigo, en su lugar porque no mejor le das un estilo general a tus `spans` usando la regla `white-space: pre-wrap;`?, de esa forma se respetaran todos los espacios en blanco y saltos de linea que tenga el span.

Comment: Esta pregunta es un duplicado de esta otra de aca:

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como evitar esto al usar nbsp; en React-native con html?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387550/como-evitar-esto-al-usar-nbsp-en-react-native-con-html)

Comment: Porfavor evita hacer la misma pregunta 2 vecez, si deseas que esta reciba una mayor atencion puedes hacerlo de diferentes maneras, pero no haciendo duplicados, pues los duplicados son perjudiciales para el sitio y se trata de evitar hacer y responder a preguntas que son duplicadas de otras, pues ya hay una respuesta para ellas, en tu caso nadie ha respondido a la otra pregunta, pero de todas maneras es mejor no hacerlo.